# Selecting empty records depending on left join other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select statement below. tblplayer contains 709 records for Game = 'FPS'.
tblPlayerPoints contains 1 record with values (2, 'FPS', 812, 0).
The sql should return 709 records which I can run through for inserting with values (1, 'FPS', playerid, 0).
However upon running the SELECT below, it only returns 708 records. So it excludes the record allready existing.

It should ignore that record because the first value (2) is different than the new first values (1). I tried adding AND tblPlayerPoints.Gamenumber < 2 but then I get 0 records instead of 709.

Upon removing tblPlayerPoints.Points IS NULL I do get 709 records. But I can't remove that line, because if a row with values (1, 'FPS', playerid, 0) allready exists it shouldn't add that line again.

```
SELECT 1 , 'FPS', tblPlayer.PlayerId, 0
FROM tblPlayer
LEFT JOIN tblPlayerPoints ON tblPlayer.Id = tblPlayerPoints.PlayerId
WHERE tblPlayer.Game = 'FPS'
AND tblPlayer.Subscription = '1'
AND tblPlayerPoints.Points IS NULL
```

Full insert example:

```
INSERT INTO tblpronoploegritpunten ("1","FPS",PlayerId,"0") 
SELECT 1 , 'FPS', tblPlayer.PlayerId, 0
FROM tblPlayer
LEFT JOIN tblPlayerPoints ON tblPlayer.Id = tblPlayerPoints.PlayerId
WHERE tblPlayer.Game = 'FPS'
AND tblPlayer.Subscription = '1'
AND tblPlayerPoints.Points IS NULL
```

This full insert should add 709 records to tblPlayerPoints
If i change the "1"s inside the full insert example (except for subscription) to "2"s it should only add 708 records because there's allready one record starting with value 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of your problem, instead of

```
and tblPlayerPoints.Gamenumber is null
```

you may want to go with

```
and IFNULL(tblPlayerPoints.Gamenumber,0) <> 1
```

Comment: it helped me solving the issue, allthough isnull does not exist. It should be and IFNULL(tblPlayerPoints.Gamenumber,0) <> 1

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes. I was thinking SQL Server, but I see the mysql tag now :)